# Why error on getContent() You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Tags: apex, error-messages, getcontent

I am getting a log error when running this code. It is launched from the report schedule.

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

The part of the code causing the problem is the `getContent()`. There are no DML statements as it gets the list of ids from the report and then passes them to a batch able class for the updating.

It was working a few hours ago, but now has stopped after I did the Test classes. I removed those changes but it still doesn't work! grr. Help really appreciated

```
global string csvList;


public void execute(Reports.NotificationActionContext context) {

        //GET ALl report info as CSV
        Reports.ReportResults results = context.getReportInstance().getReportResults();
        ReportID  = context.getReportInstance().getReportId();
        system.debug('ReportID '+ReportID );

        //Get CSV File of report

         ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/'+ReportID +'?csv=1&enc=UTF-8');

         if(!Test.isRunningTest() ){ // real
             csvList =  report.getContent().toString();
         }else{//test             
             csvList = String.valueOf('"FakeHeader","FakeHeader",\n"FakeID","FakeField"');
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours I figured it out. How could my code magically change?

When subcribing to the report I had the email notification turned out. This meant salesforce was making it's own DML calls before launching the apex class.